# How does this summation $\sum_{i=0}^\infty (1/2)^i $ equal 2?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, summation

How does this summation $\sum_{i=0}^\infty (\frac1 2)^i $ equal 2?

I'm working through the book Probability & Statistics 4th ed by DeGroot.

In chapter 2 section 2. question #17 it asks.

`Two boys A and B throw a ball at a target. Suppose that the probability that boy A will hit the target on any throw is 1/3 and the probability that boy B will hit the target on any throw is 1/4. Suppose also that boy A throws first and the two boys take turns throwing. Determine the probability that the target will be hit for the first time on the third throw of boy A.`

My question is regarding the follow up question #18.

`For the conditions of Exercise 17,determine the probability that boy A will hit the target before boy B does.`

After working out a few examples. I realized that I can solve #18 with this.

$\frac 1 3 \sum_{i=0}^\infty (\frac1 2)^i$

And so to solve the summation, I calculated the integral:

$\int_0^\infty (\frac 1 2)^xdx$

But after integrating and evaluating at 0 and infinity. I got the value:

$\frac{1}{ln(2)}$

So putting everything back together I got:

$\frac 1 3 \frac{1}{ln(2)}$

But the book got:

$\frac 1 3 (2)$

I must be doing something wrong..

Comment: Why should the integral be equal to the sum?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series). It should help you.

Comment: Here's some intuition: The first few terms of the sequence are $1, \frac 12, \frac 14, \frac {1}8,\dots$.  Plot the first few terms of the sequence of partial sums on the number line.  The first number gets you halfway from $0$ to $2$.  Then the next gets you halfway across the interval that's left over.  Then the next gets you halfway of what's left after that.  Carry this on for a while and you'll get arbitrarily close to $2$.

Comment: thanks @Bye_World intuitively that makes sense. I guess my problem lies in what Borge mentioned; that solving the integral is equal to the sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a simple sum of a geometric series - and using the technique to calculate such sum is well described here: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=calculate+geometric+series where: $a_1 = 1$, $r=1/2$, and n goes to infinity.

Comment: Thanks Moti, I totally forgot this, but I did learn geometric series a while back. And using the formula, I did get 2. For some reason I had the vague notion that to calculate the value of a summation, I could use the integral.  Is the false?

Comment: It is not false, but you get inequality and need to seek a limit. way too complicated. So you accept the answer?:)

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll look more into when I can or can't use integrals.